# Is there any relation between electride and an electron localization function (ELF)?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, condensed-matter, charge-density

I would like to know if there is any correlation between the ELF values with materials in the electronic phase, versus with the [electride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electride) phase?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago but now that it has been almost 1.5 years, can you please update us? Are you still in urgent or active need of an answer to this question?